# Query to get Max/Min row details for multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have a table structure similar to the following example:

```
DateTime              V1    V2    V3    V4    
10/10/10 12:10:00     71    24    33    40
10/10/10 12:00:00     75    22    44    12
10/10/10 12:30:00     44    21    44    33
10/10/10 12:20:00     80    11    88    12
```

With DateTime field being the unqiue and key field, I want a query to output min and max date time for each values so that it will show something like below:

```
TYPE    MIN     MINDATETIME         MAX     MAXDATETIME 
V1      44      10/10/10 12:30:00   80      10/10/10 12:20:00 
V2      11      10/10/10 12:20:00   24      10/10/10 12:10:00 
V3      33      10/10/10 12:10:00   88      10/10/10 12:20:00 
V4      12      10/10/10 12:20:00   40      10/10/10 12:10:00
```

If there are multiple rows with the same min/max value, then it should get the latest one.

With Inner Join on a field, I know to get the details of min/max row for a field, but only way I can think getting everything in one query is to union them all. I think there might be a better solution. Any help is appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd union 4 queries if it was me, there may well be a better way.

Comment: What RDBMS and version? And do you need the data exactly like that output? This is an UNPIVOT followed by aggregates stuff if you do...

Comment: I am using sql server 2008. Yes the main idea is to get the datetime corresponding to the min and max value of a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unpivot into useful rows ("normalise")
- Work out MIN/MAX per Type, allowing for MAX datetime if ties
- Extract MIN/MAX values

Hey presto...

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (
    DateTimeKey datetime NOT NULL,
    V1 int NOT NULL,
    V2 int NOT NULL,
    V3 int NOT NULL,
    V4 int NOT NULL
);

INSERT @foo (DateTimeKey, V1, V2, V3, V4)
SELECT '10/10/10 12:10:00',     71,    24,    33,    40 
UNION ALL SELECT '10/10/10 12:00:00',     75,    22,    44,    12 
UNION ALL SELECT '10/10/10 12:30:00',     44,    21,    44,    33 
UNION ALL SELECT '10/10/10 12:20:00',     80,    11,    88,    12;


WITH cTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        [Type], [Value], DateTimeKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Value], DateTimeKey DESC) AS TypeRankMin, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Value] DESC, DateTimeKey DESC) AS TypeRankMax
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            [Type], [Value], DateTimeKey
        FROM 
           (SELECT DateTimeKey, V1, V2, V3, V4 FROM @foo) p
           UNPIVOT
           ([Value] FOR [Type] IN (V1, V2, V3, V4)) AS unp
        ) bar
)
SELECT
    Mn.[Type], [MIN], MINDATETIME, [MAX], MAXDATETIME
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [Type], [Value] AS [MIN], DateTimeKey AS MINDATETIME
        FROM
            cTE
        WHERE
            TypeRankMin = 1
    ) Mn
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            [Type], [Value] AS [MAX], DateTimeKey AS MAXDATETIME
        FROM
            cTE
        WHERE
            TypeRankMax = 1
    ) Mx ON Mn.[Type] = Mx.[Type];
```

Comment: this is great gbn. it worked perfect. but a question: I modified the query to have only MAX value just to compare the performance of this with my query since I had only max (my query as mentioned earlier did unions of inner joins for each value fields). for a table of approx. 82000 rows on 18 value fields(v1, v2, etc.), i got the results out in around 4 sec. but this query took around 15 sec. know why?

Comment: The data is in a poor form for querying, and this solution does a lot of processing. Try Andomar's solution to compare

Answer (score 0):

You can get both max and min values in a single query. To get max/min datetime you will have to join the max/min query back to the table (once per every value)

something to the effect of:

```
select values.*, mint.timestamp, maxt.timestamp from
    (select MIN(value) as minv, MAX(value) as maxv from table group by value) values,
    table mint,
    table maxt
where 
    mint.value = values.minv
    maxt.value = values.maxv
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but it seems to solve this basic case:

```
create table t(a int,b int);
insert into t(a,b) values(1,2),(2,3),(-1,-10);

select max(t1.a),min(t1.a),max(t2.b),min(t2.b) from t as t1,t as t2;
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| max(t1.a) | min(t1.a) | max(t2.b) | min(t2.b) |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         2 |        -1 |         3 |       -10 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with normalizing your data.  Since V2 does not depend on V1, they should not be in the same row.  Here's a normalizing query:

```
SELECT DateTime, 'V1' as Type, V1 as Value FROM @data
UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V2', V2 FROM @data
UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V3', V3 FROM @data
UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V4', V4 FROM @data
```

With that, what remains is the "selecting records holding group-wise maximum with tie" problem.  One way to solve that is:

```
;WITH normal AS (
    SELECT DateTime, 'V1' as Type, V1 as Value FROM @data
    UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V2', V2 FROM @data
    UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V3', V3 FROM @data
    UNION ALL select DateTime, 'V4', V4 FROM @data
)
SELECT *
FROM    (SELECT  DISTINCT Type FROM normal) dd
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT   TOP 1 DateTime MINDATETIME, Value MIN
        FROM     normal di
        WHERE    di.Type = dd.Type
        ORDER BY Value, DateTime desc
        ) dimin
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT   TOP 1 DateTime MAXDATETIME, Value MAX
        FROM     normal di
        WHERE    di.Type = dd.Type
        ORDER BY Value desc, DateTime desc
        ) dimax
```

The `dd` query returns the Types (V1, V2, ...)  The first `cross apply` searches for the minimums for that type, and the second `cross apply` searches for the maximums.

Answer (score -1):

i read the question and thought: i'd rather do that in php than sql.

then i read the answers and i thought: i'd **really** rather do that in php than sql.